# Anywhere Elementor Pro : custom Query Filter

Tags: wordpress, filter, taxonomy, elementor

I use anywhere Elementor Pro.
In an archive, I need to create a custom Query filter in a "AE - Post Blocks".
I created a function in order to apply the filter nammed: "vedette_favorites_filter".
Here is the function:

```
function vedette_favorites_function($query_args){
    $query_args = array (
                        array   (
                            'taxonomy' => 'en_vedette', 
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => 'mes-favorites',
                                ),
                            );
}
add_filter('vedette_favorites_filter', 'vedette_favorites_function');
```

In the field "Query Filter" of "AE - Post Blocks", I inserted the name "vedette_favorites_filter".

Nothing appends!
Can you, please, help me and telling where is my mistake.
Regards,
Bruno

Answer (score 1):

The right code is:

```
function vedette_favorites_function($query_args){
    $query_args =   array   (
                        'post_type' => 'recette',
                        'tax_query' => array(
                                            array   (
                                                'taxonomy' => 'en_vedette',
                                                'field' => 'slug',
                                                'terms' => 'mes-favorites',
                                                    ),
                                            ),
                            );
    return $query_args;
}
add_filter('vedette_favorites_filter', 'vedette_favorites_function');
```